# What can this small Excel formula do?

Tags: excel

TDay = Daytime Temperatures. Column A contains names of the months.

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(TDay; 1+($A2-1)*12):INDEX(TDay; A2*$12))
```

The formula doesn't work, some error with row_num.

Comment: What is your question?  Are you asking what the formula can do?  Why it isn't working?  Be specific.

Comment: It would make more sense if the values in column A were years rather than months, then it would be expanding them up into months and taking the average of the corresponding temperatures, but we need to see what the sheet looks like really.

Answer (score 1):

> TDay = Daytime Temperatures. Column A contains **names of the months.**

To answer your question, (*What can this small Excel formula do?*), It cannot do anything except produce `#VALUE!` errors. If column A truly contains *names of the months* then (as text) you cannot add or multiply numbers against the values in column A without producing an error.

However, if the values in column A are actually dates with a custom number format of `mmm` or `mmmm` then they could have numbers added or multiplied against then. If this was the case then you seem to be imitating an `AVERAGEIFS` formula by specifying the start and stop rows of data within the `TDay` named range that will be passed to the `AVERAGE` function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this part: ($A2-1)12. It seems like sign / operator is missed (depends of application), for example ($A2-1)*12.

Comment: You are right. This is not the right one. Edited and changed to "=AVERAGE(INDEX(TDay;1+($A2-1)*12):INDEX(TDay;A2*$12))